# How to reduce long template rendering time?

Tags: python, django, optimization

I am trying to optimize my view-template rendering. At this moment I have such picture:
[image]
As you see:
 `SQL timing` lasts **~0.5sec**,
 `TemplateTiming` **~2sec**,
 but `Total Time` is **almost 9 seconds**!
Also I have a timer in my *view* - it shows **~0.6 seconds** of *view* work. When the view prints "Finished" - after that goes a lot of time when I see this page render finished in my browser. 

 **Can somebody explain me from where the hell additional 9-0.5-2-0.6 = 5.9 seconds come from?**
I have quite a long list to render, with pagination, ~12k items. If there is smaller item amount - the render time is also smaller. Sometimes I also render this page with list of ~20k items, but with another combination of queries/filters - and the total time is much smaller ~4~5 seconds. What is going wrong and when?

**UPDATE** Looks like I have found out the cause of the problem, but I still can't get what is wrong. I have this piece of code in my view:

```
 #1st definition of products_list
products_list = Product.objects.select_related('shop', 'brand', 'sale', 'promo', 'category') \
                                    .only('product_id', 'title', 'slug', 'product_url',
                                          'price', 'prev_price', 'brand',
                                          'sale__percent', 'sale__old_price',
                                          'promo__promo_description', 'promo__promo_url',
                                          'shop__shop_name', 'shop__country',
                                          'category__category_name')\
                                    .filter(in_stock = True)
      if sale != None:
            cached_shop = cache.get(shop)
            if cached_shop != None:
                #2nd definition, replaces products_list
                products_list = Product.objects.select_related('shop', 'brand', 'sale', 'promo', 'category').filter(product_id__in=cached_shop[sale])                          #PRODUCS_LIST
            else:
                #this piece of code uses 1st definition of products_list
                if sale == "19%":
                    products_list = products_list.filter(sale__percent__gt=0, sale__percent__lt=20)
                elif sale == "20%-49%":
                    products_list = products_list.filter(sale__percent__gte=20, sale__percent__lt=50)
                elif sale == "50%-69%":
                    products_list = products_list.filter(sale__percent__gte=50, sale__percent__lt=70)
                elif sale == "70%-89%":
                    products_list = products_list.filter(sale__percent__gte=70, sale__percent__lt=90)
                elif sale == "90%+":
                    products_list = products_list.filter(sale__percent__gte=90)
```

As you see it tries to find the list of product.id in the cache, and if cache not found - it filters the Product table in the straight way. But if I remove the cache condition - the speed dramatically decreases, almost 2 times- **Picture 2**.
[image]
 Why this happens? I see that when I use *cache* - `SQL timings` are **lower** than when using *standard filtering*, but the `Total timings` are **2 times longer**! I am trying to implement better things, but get worse results.

Comment: the django's cache offers nice solutions to your problem

Comment: Do you mean to cache parts of the template?

Comment: consider rendering the page on the browser with javascript, this way you only sending data (json) from the web

Comment: shahaf, do u have any links to useful resources how that can be done? I have a small experience with JavaScript for the moment.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching  See here how you can cache a html template

Comment: yep, I know that. But my html page is different for different filters applied. As I understand - this can't be cached. Or I should cache every possible filter combination, what is not so good, I think.